# Asp.net MVC5 Bootstrap: Can not fetch selected value in edit page Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand why my edit page can not fetch the selected value in my Dropdownlist.

My Create Function is working fine, but my Edit Page is not displaying the selected value in my Dropdownlist. I am trying to fetch the selected Value by using Viewbags and if i am debugging, the id's are present.

This is my `Edit()`

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SeminarErstellen seminarerstellen = db.SeminarErstellen.Find(id);
        if (seminarerstellen == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.FileUploadId = new SelectList(db.FileUpload, "FileUploadId", "FilePath", seminarerstellen.FileUploadId);
        ViewBag.LehrbeauftragterId = new SelectList(db.Lehrbeauftragter, "LehrbeauftragterId", "Vorname", seminarerstellen.LehrbeauftragterId);
        ViewBag.SeminarStatiId = new SelectList(db.SeminarStati, "SeminarStatiId", "StatusTyp", seminarerstellen.SeminarStatiId);
        ViewBag.SeminarTypId = new SelectList(db.SeminarTyp, "SeminarTypId", "Seminarbezeichnung", seminarerstellen.SeminarTypId);
        return View(seminarerstellen);
    }
```

And this is the DropdownList of my View: The problem is, its always selecting the first item of my Dropdownlist and not the selected one...I hope you understand...

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SeminarTypId, "SeminarTypId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @* This Dropdown is selecting the right value but without Bootstrap!*@
            @*@Html.DropDownList("SeminarTypId", String.Empty)*@
            @* This line is selecting the wrong item, its selecting the first item of the list*@
            @Html.DropDownList("SeminarTypId", (SelectList)ViewBag.SeminarTypId,  new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SeminarTypId)
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removal of Your Confusion

......................

- 1. The bootstrap Classes have nothing to do with your DropDownList
- 2.The Problem with you is Naming Convention

***Solution***

Problem is in your ViewBag property name. Because it is same as your property in Model it will not work.

---

`YourCode`

`Controller`

```
ViewBag.SeminarTypId = new SelectList(db.SeminarTyp, "SeminarTypId", minarbezeichnung",seminarerstellen.SeminarTypId);
```

`View`

```
@Html.DropDownList("SeminarTypId", (SelectList)ViewBag.SeminarTypId,  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

---

`Modification`

`Controller`

```
ViewBag.SeminarTypId123 = new SelectList(db.SeminarTyp, "SeminarTypId", minarbezeichnung",seminarerstellen.SeminarTypId);
```

`View`

```
@Html.DropDownList("SeminarTypId", (SelectList)ViewBag.SeminarTypId123,  new { @class = "form-control" })
```